# How do I fetch a string from a server?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let's say I have an html file on my server called sample.txt (it's a plain text document)

Inside the sample.txt file is a line that says http://sample.com

In my app's delegate I have this code

`NSDictionary* defaults = @{@"server_addr": @"http://sample.com"};
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaults];`

Instead of having to change the `server_addr` within the app when needing to change servers, I'd like to change the `server_addr` from outside the app by calling whatever line of code is in sample.txt on my server.

How can I do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` to download file from server.

Or if You want to check version data of server You can get even `"Last-Modified"` field from HTTP response header, and compare with current data version in your app.

Read the downloaded file to get what data that You want.

Comment: How could I go about doing that? Do you have a link to an example or sample by chance? That would really be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: @Creagen have to write a lot of code for example, so I'm sory that I can't show for You here. You must find how to use NSURLSessionDownloadTask by your self, and I'm sure it work. I hope this will help